# Assigning initial value when using the out key word c#

Tags: c#, out

```
static void Main (string [] args)
{
 int myNum;
 Double (out myNum);
}
static void Double (out int myInt)
{
 myInt=10; //need to assign a initial value here 
 myInt*=2;
}
```

In the above case I will have a compiler error if not assigning an initial value for myInt.

```
static void Main (string [] args)
{
 int sum;
 int prod;
 Calculator (5,10, out sum, out prod);
}
static void Calculator (int a, int b, out int sum, out int prod)
{
 sum =a+b;
 prod= a*b;
}
```

In this case, I don't need to assign a value for a or b, my code runs fine, no compiler error, why? when do I need to assign an initial value to the variables?

Comment: In the second case, the initial value for `sum` is `a + b` and for `prod` it is `a * b`. Nothing wrong with that...

Comment: @Sweeper so it doesn't need to be a actual value like case 1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "actual" here. `a+b` is just as "actual" as `10`. Why don't you think `a+b` is an actual value?

Comment: I've removed unrelated `out` concerns from the question... Feel free to revert the edit if you believe that `out` is actually the cause of the problem.

Comment: In the second example if you remove `=1` and `=2` and just have `int a;` and `int b;` you will get the same error.

Comment: @Sweeper I thought it needs to be a real number, like in case 1. so I can't do '''int sum;''' but '''int sum=a+b;''' IS assigning initial value to sum right?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't assign any value to a and b if you look at my original post. that's why I'm asking why I don't need to assign anything to a or b.

Comment: `out` parameter must be assigned a value inside the method body before use... in `Double` method, `myInt` parameter is `out` you are trying to assign value to it but origin of the value which is the variable itself and it does not have any value assigned before.. that's why you are getting error in `Double` method.

Comment: `Calculator` in calculator method, `a` and `b` are not out parameters, their values are expected to be passed by the caller of the method. So they are not required to be assigned in the method before being used. That's why you won't get error there..

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you so much, so 'sum=a+b;' means 'sum' is assigned, even though this a and b are not assigned. right?